# upgrade cloud enterprise edition with specific steps

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-cloud

I want to upgrade cloud enterprise edition from 2.3.2-p2 to 2.4.2 but not getting proper steps so anyone can guide me for same.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following steps:

**Step 1:**

*Take the DB backup. For doing this, you need to login Magento cloud server and run the following command:*

```
vendor/bin/ece-tools db-dump
```

**Step 2:** *Run the following command in your local machine where your project repository setup*

```
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.2 <2.4.3" --no-update
```

**Step 3:** Run the following command

```
composer update
```

**Step 4:**

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Step 5:**

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Test all in your local and commit to Magento cloud. These commands are basic.

[More detail](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html#complete-the-upgrade)